# Почему Visual Studio подчёркивает красным метод break в цикле

Tags: c#, циклы, консоль, break

Почему при использовании тернарного оператора в случае если условие будет равно false не возможно использовать break?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Притом что через полную конструкцию if else всё работает как надо
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: обычно если подвести курсор на подчеркнутое, то будет написана причина

Comment: Весь этот код это `string s = text.TrimStart();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тернарник это сокращённо

```
if (..) 
    return ЧТО-ТО 
else 
    return что-то
```

Как думаете, конструкция `return break;`  валидная?

Comment: Почему то когда я пишу полную конструкцию if else, притом что в if закидываю i++, а в else break, то всё работает

Comment: То же самое только через тернарный оператор не работает

Comment: нет не тоже самое... else break; или return break; - разницу видите?